# Adblock plus: how to inverse a :-abp-has() selector?

Tags: css, adblock

I use Extended CSS selectors (Adblock Plus specific).

My question is:

```
example.com#?##plist > ul > li:-abp-has(> div > div.p-operate)
```

hide items that I exactly want to show.

How can I make an inverse selection?
I want to achieve effect like this:

```
example.com#?##plist > ul > li:**-abp-not-has**(> div > div.p-operate)
```

Comment: Try `:not(:-abp-has(> div > div.p-operate))`

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks! But it doesn't work. Chrome complains "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#plist > ul > li:not(' is not a valid selector."